# order execution report( real time update of order placed via API) to another backend system

Tags: java

I need to push the order execution reports (real-time updates of orders placed via API) to another backend system. After sending 500 to 1000 real-time updates of orders posted via API within 1 to 2 minutes the other system is not able to respond.

Is this the correct way to implement real-time updates via a postback URL, or should I implement it by creating a queue (producer, consumer)?